# Angular scanner autosubmit

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am new to angular.js but I am trying to learn. I created a form that allows me to search using a barcode scanner and I can then press a button to submit. This step seems redundant. I would like the scanner to search and then submit the information in one action but I am not sure how to do this. Here is the current code.

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="SearchItemCtrl">

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>{{trans('sale.search_item')}} <input ng-model="searchKeyword" class="form-control"></label>

        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items  | filter: searchKeyword | limitTo:10">

                <td>@{{item.item_name}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" type="button" ng-click="addSaleTemp(item, newsaletemp)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your scanner send a return after the string?  I know some scanners have this ability, you could then likely add a `ngKeyPress` or `ngChange` attribute to detect the new line command to "auto submit".  If the scanner is not able to do this, another option (assuming all UPC codes will have the same length) is to check for the length of the text and auto submit when it reaches the appropriate number of characters for the UPC.

Comment: I do not believe my scanner has that capability. So you are saying that I should be able to associate that when a certain number of characters displays from the scanner it will automatically enable the ng-click= on the button?

Comment: You would add an `ng-change="MyMethodName"` and in the `MyMethodName` you would check for `searchKeyword.Length == 9`(or whatever length of the expected UPC).  Then you can call `addSaleTemp()` directly from that method without having to virtually click the appropriate button.